# TableView Cell Custom type Text Overlaps itself or is Blank

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, core-data

Hoping someone can advise me on the correct method to populate a `UITableViewCell` with custom labels. I keep running into the same issues , either the label is blank or when the table fills up with `cells` reused ones show overlapping `label` text.

I have followed what has been advised for others here but each way I do it something breaks.

** Update **

I have changed the code to below and have most of it working except when I select a cell the label overlaps as in the screenshot below. The code for the tutorial I am using can be found here: https://github.com/funkyboy/Core-Data-on-iOS-5-Tutorial--How-To-Work-with-Relations-and-Predicates

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

FailedBankInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

CGRect infoFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 16);
UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:infoFrame];
infoLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
infoLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
infoLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
infoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
infoLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
infoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", info.city, info.state];
[cell addSubview:infoLabel];

return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

FailedBankInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *theLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
theLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",
                 info.city, info.state];

}
```

Because I am using the Prototype `Cell` with Core Data and `fetchedresultcontroller` the `if(!cell)` is never called. I changed the tag to be the indexPath.row number. Every tutorial I have followed works fine if you use the predefined `cell` types. If I use Custom with my own labels it never works out. Should I not use a fetchedresultscontroller for the tableview data?  If I change the city title in the detail view and save it the following code gets called:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

switch(type) {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                           arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                           arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
    }
}
```

Here are some screenshots:

[image: storyboard]

[image: changed cell]

[image: selected cell]

Comment: Did you try my solution? if yes and it worked please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: @MongiZaidi Yes I did Mongi but the label doesn't show at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Update - When using custom cells remove the prototype cell as you don't need it!!

I finally figured out why it was not working. The whole problem is the Prototype Cell because you have to set a reuse Identifier and in most of the tutorials they use the string "Cell".

When the tableview load it already has a cell in it with the Identifier "Cell" so it doesn't create a new cell it just reuses the cell that has the Identifier "Cell".

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

The above block if (cell == nil) is never called because it is reusing the Prototype cell that is already there. The other problem is creating the label below this block as in:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
FailedBankInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

CGRect infoFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 16);
UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:infoFrame];
infoLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
infoLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
infoLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
infoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
infoLabel.tag = 101;
infoLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",
         info.city, info.state];
[cell.contentView addSubview:infoLabel];

return cell;
}
```

This appears to work fine as it does create the Label but when you scroll the screen you find that Labels are overlapping themselves as in my problem.  This is because when a cell goes off screen and comes back on the cellForRowAtIndexPath reuses a cell that already has a label and creates another Label over the top. This keeps happening until you have 7, 8 or more Labels overlapping on the same cell. I worked this out by putting an NSlog in the didSelectRowatIndex to count the number of subviews here:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSLog(@"Count is:%i", [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].contentView.subviews count]);
}
```

So what you need to do is create the custom Label inside the if (cell == nil) and use an else to only set the text of the Label.  The key for this to work is that each cell has to have a unique reuse Identifier so when CellforRowatIndexPath is called it creates a new cell  the first time it appears. When that cell goes off screen and comes back on a new cell is not created it just reuses the existing one and changes the text without creating another Label. I have checked this with another NSlog in the if (cell == nil) it fires once for each cell and after that it doesn't fire because it reuses dequeued cells. I just used a string "myCell" + indexPath.row for the Identifier. In the storyboard I still have the Identifier of "Cell" for the Prototype cell. It complains if you don't have something in there. Here is my final code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *myCellID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myCell%i", indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myCellID];

FailedBankInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:myCellID];
    CGRect infoFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 16);
    UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:infoFrame];
    infoLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    infoLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    infoLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    infoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    infoLabel.tag = 101;
    infoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", info.name];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:infoLabel];
}
else {
    UILabel *theLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    theLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", info.name];
}

return cell;
}
```

Also I am still using the code:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

FailedBankInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *theLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
theLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", info.name];
}
```

To update the label text when the Core data object changes with the following code:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

switch(type) {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                           arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                           arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
  }
}
```

I also found sometimes when segueing back to the table view the table doesn't always update so to fix this you can use:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear {
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Thanks for all of your input it did help me come to a solution and I hope that this helps anyone else who is experiencing the same issue. I think I have explained it well enough. I'm not an expert by any means. Just another guy trying to build an App :)

Answer (score 5):

I just **fixed** it with just 2-3 lines of code. This is happening because When tableView display your content by using this.

```
[cell.contentView addSubView:myView];
```

Now it will work perfectly if your tableView is not Scrolling but when you scroll your TableView then it overlap the content because it will not clear old content from memory and you can see memory usage in Memory Debug Session. Now your Memory Consumption will be Increasing with scrolling.

So the Best Solution is to Clear all the old Content from Cell's contentView First before adding new Content to Cell Memory. So that It will run Smoothly.

I have used following code for Clearing old memory from Cell's contentView before adding any Content to contentView.

```
for (id object in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
    [object removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I think this is the Perfect Solution. But I still need Reviews from you Guys. Please share your Experience.

Answer (score 1):

For storyboards create custom cell class as below.Set your labels visually and set required properties like color,font,size etc

```
myCell.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myCell : UITableViewCell

//connect your labels and image as below

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel3;

@end


yourViewController.m

//Set up your custom cell

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
myCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[myCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

}

cell.myLabel1.text = @"hello1";
cell.myLabel2.text = @"hello2";
cell.myLabel3.text = @"hello3";

[cell.myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"google.jpg"]];
return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    FailedBankInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CGRect infoFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 16);
    UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:infoFrame];
    infoLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    infoLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    infoLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    infoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    infoLabel.tag = 101;
    infoLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",
             info.city, info.state];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:infoLabel];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you please check my answer and let me know what you think?

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of problems with tableview many times before. The best solution I found so far is creating my own "reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier" method (in myViewController.m) and then using it to get the cell in "cellForRowAtIndexPath method".
In your case it will be like this :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
   FailedBankInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   CGRect infoFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 16);
   UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:infoFrame];
   infoLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   infoLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
   infoLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
   infoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
   infoLabel.tag = 101;
   infoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", info.city, info.state];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:b];
   return cell;
}
```

Now you just need to get the Label with its tag and change its value in your cellForRow method like this :

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [self reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier withIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    UILabel *infoLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
    FailedBankInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    infoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", info.city, info.state];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: The if (nil == cell) never gets called. So the cells come up blank. See the solution I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.I think this is because we are reusing the identifier so cells are overlapped on others. The below lines of code worked for me..

UITableViewCell  *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tick clears Graphic context in the property section of that label in storyboard.

Comment: this should be a comment please.